# Can I sell starting gear in Adventurers League play?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, dnd-adventurers-league

I'm starting a new AL game (as a player) and I have a question that's not addressed in the AL material.

According to Adventurers League Player's Guide (page 4)

> When you create your D&D Adventurers League character for the current season, take starting equipment as determined by your class and background. You cannot roll for your starting wealth.

Meaning I can't start with whatever I want. However, I am playing a ranged-focused fighter, so the second gear option is of no use to me:

- (*a*) a martial weapon and a shield or (*b*) two  martial weapons

**Can I choose any two martial weapons and sell them for half price to use for purchasing other gear before play? And is there a restriction on how much gold I can get?**

For example, two hand crossbows (martial ranged weapons) can net me 75 gp when sold, or two greatswords nets me 50 gp when sold.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can definitely sell the items at the end of the episode or adventure, per the AL Player's Guide (pg 7). Anything else is up to your DM. Note that these are distinct from the end of a session.

> At the end of an episode or adventure (and sometimes 
>   during an adventure), you can buy or sell mundane 
>   items. Any gems, jewelry, art objects, and trade goods
>   you find during adventures are automatically converted 
>   to their full value in gold and divided up among the 
>   adventurers in your group.
>   Arms, armor, and other equipment fetch half their 
>   cost if you sell them.

http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources

Answer (score 3):

Update for Season 9:

Adventurers League Player's Guide Version 9.1 (17 September 2019):

> Your character can sell or buy spell components and equipment found in the Player’s Handbook or any player resources

Adventurers League Frequently Asked Questions Version 9.0 (17 September 2019):

> ... mundane items ... are still sold at half their listed value.

Note:

> ... mundane equipment and treasure indicated in adventures is
>   ignored—even if listed under a treasure subheading; it’s just not
>   found by the characters.